# Last thumbnail in carousel screws up rotation

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, thumbnails

Can someone take a look at this code and try to help me out?
It doesn't matter when you click the 6th thumbnail, as soon as it is clicked, it screws up the carousel. Thumbs 1 through 5 work great, it's just when the 6th is clicked that it turns into a problem.

This is in WordPress PHP, so I can't do much but offer this pastebin link:

http://pastebin.com/MeZWL8fX

Comment: I fixed this line of code, but it's still not solved.

Comment: Also, remove this whole set of code doesn't affect anything with the slider:

`$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function(){
   var index = $('.carousel-inner .item.active').index();
   $('.thumbs .item[data-slide-number="'+(index-1)+'"]').addClass('active');
});`